# Rails and Postgres HSTORE Attribute Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I have set up Postgres' `hstore` data type in my Rails 4 app and it works perfectly.

Is there a way to define default data type castings for each attribute in a Hstore column? This example explains:

{ "key1" => "1", "key2" => "2" }

I would like to retrieve "1" and "2" from this Model as INT by default. Is there any way to do this using Hstore or do I need to add ".to_i" every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gem [hstore_accessor](https://github.com/devmynd/hstore_accessor).

The available types are: `string`, `integer`, `float`, `decimal`, `datetime`, `date`, `boolean`, `array` (deprecated), and `hash` (deprecated).